# Load JSON array for chart( ZingChart)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, charts

I tried to load this sample of data from external file to line zingchart, but nothing appears in chart, any suggestions ? thanks for answers.

```
var chartData = [{"time":"1706043693.219217:","dac":"3000,","adc":"406","voltage":"0.4956"},{"time":"1706043693.231481:","dac":"3000,","adc":"413","voltage":"0.5042"},{"time":"1706043693.242824:","dac":"3000,","adc":"409","voltage":"0.4993"},{"time":"1706043693.253953:","dac":"3000,","adc":"413","voltage":"0.5042"},{"time":"1706043693.265034:","dac":"3000,","adc":"406","voltage":"0.4956"},{"time":"1706043693.276092:","dac":"3000,","adc":"410","voltage":"0.5005"},{"time":"1706043693.287171:","dac":"3000,","adc":"409","voltage":"0.4993"},{"time":"1706043693.298221:","dac":"3000,","adc":"411","voltage":"0.5017"},{"time":"1706043693.309273:","dac":"3000,","adc":"411","voltage":"0.5017"},{"time":"1706043693.320340:","dac":"3000,","adc":"407","voltage":"0.4968"},{"time":"1706043693.331321:","dac":"3000,","adc":"410","voltage":"0.5005"},{"time":"1706043693.342464:","dac":"3000,","adc":"407","voltage":"0.4968"},{"time":"1706043693.353505:","dac":"3000,","adc":"406","voltage":"0.4956"},{"time":"1706043693.364545:","dac":"3000,","adc":"409","voltage":"0.4993"}];

var myConfig = {
  "type": "line",
  "legend": {},
   "plot":{
"aspect":"spline"
},
 "title": {
   "text":"Back heating"
},
  "preview":{ adjustLayout:true},
  "scale-x": {
    "zooming": true,
    "zoom-to": [0, 50],
    "item": {
      "font-size": 10
    }
  },
  "scale-x": {
    "zooming": true,
    "label": {
    "text": "axisX",
    "font-size": 16
    }
  },
  "scale-y": {
    "zooming": true,
    "guide": {
      "line-style": "dotted"
    },
    "item": {
      "font-size": 10
    },
    "label": {
    "text": "axisY",
    "font-size": 16
    }
  },
  "plot": {
    "line-width": 1,
    "aspect":"spline"
  },
  "crosshair-x": {
    "plot-label": {
      "text": "%v"
    },
    "scale-label": {
      "visible": false
    }
  },
  "crosshair-y": {
    "type": "multiple",
    "scale-label": {
      "visible": false
    }
  },
  "series": [{
    "values": chartData
  }
  ]
};

zingchart.render({
  id: 'myChart',
  data: myConfig,
  height: 400,
  width: 600
});
```

Comment: it is working for you ?

Comment: yes thanks for solution :) but there is one thing: axis x = time and axis y = adc,dac and voltage if you understand 
it shows a lot of series

Comment: Don't forget to accept answer in order to help other people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass object in this way:

```
"series": [{
   "values": [3, 4, 11, 5, 19, 7]
 }, {
   "values": [9, 19, 15, 25, 12, 14]
 }, {
   "values": [15, 29, 19, 21, 25, 26]
 },{
   .........
 }]
```

So you have to use `map` method in order to achive this array:

```
var chartD=chartData.map(function(item){
    var array=[item.time,item.dac,item.adc,item.voltage];
    return {"values":array};
});
```

The last step is to assing `array` to `series` properties.

```
"series": chartD
```

Here is [working solution.](https://jsfiddle.net/kgsshk5e/6/)